# 404 error for views for AWS but not on local deployment with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot

For practice, I deployed a Spring Boot application to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment. I have been able to run the application just fine locally. Since Spring Boot comes with a built in Tomcat, I used a Java AWS environment (not the Tomcat one). In the logs, it looks like the application is booting up correctly. However, for some reason, when I navigate to the root page (which is mapped to index.html), I get the following error:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
```

> ```
> Sun Jan 07 18:22:33 UTC 2018
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> /WEB-INF/index.html
> ```

This happens for just about any mapping. Again, I do *not* have this problem on my local server. My view resolver is as follows

```
 public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/view/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return resolver;
}
```

It looks to me as though the resolver is picking off the right paths; is does something about the paths change once I deploy this to an EC? In your response, please treat me like a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting 404 errors is because the jar file you are deploying to Elastic Beanstalk does not include the WEB-INF folder. The correct the problem, you can do the following (I will assume you are using gradle; you can search for the maven equivalent if necessary):

1. Add " apply plugin: 'war' " to your build.gradle file. This will cause "gradle clean build" to now build a war file instead of a jar file.
2. Deploy that war file.

It is possible that you may need to perform some further adjustments to correct the problem. But at the end of the day, you should be able to look inside your "war" file and see the contents of your WEB-INF folder. Once you've managed that and can run the executable locally (like java -jar app.war), then you should be able to deploy it successfully to AWS. It is also worth noting that you want to cd until you are *inside* the folder where your war is before trying to run it. Otherwise, your run will pick up the WEB-INF contents from your local system via the context.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find an alternative approach for deployment: Containerize the application, then deploy it to the AWS docker environment.  If you run into this 404 issue while trying to deploy a Spring Boot application, remedying it might take more effort to figure out than you might care for. I had never Dockerized an application before, but doing that ended up being rather straightforward.

TL;DR: Don't try to deploy a Spring Boot App to a Tomcat or Java AWS environment. Containerize it and use the Docker AWS environment.

EDIT: I am looking back on this post several months later with some new knowledge: It is worth noting that this only worked because my docker build command included the WEB-INF contents in the container (as it includes everything in the passed context).